# find all VS-projects that compile to a .NET 3.5 console application

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, select-string

I have a deeply nested repository, with lots of Visual Studio projects. I need to find all projects, which have **TargetFramework 3.5** and **Output Type 'console application'**.

I figured out that console applications have this in their csproj-file:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

And applications with a window have this:

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

This allows me find all files with extension csproj, which compile to a console application.

```
$csproj_ConsoleExes = gci -Recurse *.csproj | select-string "<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>"
```

What I need to do next: I need to filter only those projects with target-framework 3.5. But since **$csproj_ConsoleExes** contains search results I don't know how to apply **select-string** again.
**select-string** only work with input-objects of type **FileInfo**.

Any  help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s ability to accept *multiple* search patterns, which allows you to then use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to determine all those files where *both* patterns matched:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.csproj |
  Select-String -SimpleMatch '<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>',
                             '<TargetFramework>net35</TargetFramework>' | 
    Group-Object Path |
      Where-Object Count -eq 2 | 
        ForEach-Object Name
```

The above outputs the full paths of all `*.csproj` files in which *both* patterns were found.

Note:

- This approach only works if, for each search pattern, at most *one* line per input file matches, which should be true for `.csproj` files.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69185292/45375) for a solution for cases where this assumption cannot be made.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the items in **$csproj_ConsoleExes** to type **FileInfo** with this:

```
$csproj_Console_Items = $csproj_ConsoleExes| select Path | get-item
```

The above line first gets the path of every item and pipes it to get-item, which is then turned into a FileInfo-object.

Then you can find all lines containing **TargetFrameworkVersion**

```
$csproj_Console_TargetFrameworkVersion=$csproj_Console_Items | select-string "<TargetFrameworkVersion>"
```

Now you could again get the path and pipe it to **get-item** to get a new collection of type FileInfo.