# One liner to find files that match two strings on different lines

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Currently on version 4.0. I am easily able to find files containing one string. Trying to do something slightly more complex with two strings on different lines has not worked out. The problem is apparently due to the way lines are evaluated individually and results are piped as objects between commands making the obvious solutions do not work.

```
# Works, so simple
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "Test1" -List | Select Path

# Fail
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "Test1.+Test2" -List | Select Path

# Fail
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "Test1" -List | Select-String -Pattern "Test2" -List | Select Path
```

Conceptually this is so simple, but I've been spinning my wheels on finding a solution. Might be easier in newer version but not able to update on server involved. I could write a script to get to the solution in Python, but at this point I want to make PowerShell do it out of spite.

Knowing what is returned from each command, how to get underlying object data, how to then pipe that data to subsequent commands, etc has repeatedly been an issue for me with PowerShell :(

Comment: I don't have a version 4 to test but I think it should be the same. First: you don't need `Get-ChildItem` in front of the `Select-String`. You can provide a path directly. Second: the parameter `-Pattern` takes an array of patterns. If I got it right it should work for your requirement.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The following commands use `Where-Object` to test for our conditions.

---

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { 
    ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'test1' -Quiet) -and
    ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'test2' -Quiet) 
}
```

This line checks if the file piped from Get-ChildItem (represented by `$_`) matches both 'test1' AND 'test2'.  Using `-Quiet` parameter will make it so that `Select-String` returns true if it finds a match or false if it doesn't.

---

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object {
    ($_ | Select-String -Pattern 'test1', 'test2' | 
        Group-Object -Property 'Pattern' ).Count -eq 2
    }
```

With this line I give `Select-String` 2 patterns to look for.  This will not ensure that both patterns are matched, but instead will return results for each that are matched.  On the `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` objects returned by Select-String is a property called `Pattern`.  If I use `Group-Object` to group all the MatchInfo results I got back by the property 'Pattern' I can then check to see if I end up with 2 group objects, one for each of my patterns.  If true, the object is returned by `Where-Object`

---

Just as with Python or any other languages there are commands/methods and parameters you need to discover and learn that will make your life easier and usually there is more than one way to do something.

Make use of the built-in help PowerShell provides to get to know the command and the objects that these commands produce.  `Get-Command`, `Get-Help`, `Get-Member` are arguably 3 of the most useful cmdlets, especially to people new to or struggling with PowerShell

Comment: Nicely done, and good tips on discovery. It is possible to make do with a single `Select-String` call overall, however
(though, depending on file size and intra-file location of the matches, even a two-calls-per-file solution could be faster, due to the short-circuiting that `-Quiet` provides).
Can I suggest spreading your commands across multiple lines, so that getting to the interesting parts doesn't require horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Thank you @mklement0.  I did also consider this double-call to the file and came to the same conclusion as you, that by using '-Quiet` the call will return as soon as the first match is found possibly cutting down on the time taken to complete.  I guess the least performant scenario would be that a match is found for the first term somewhere near the bottom of the file and then no match is found for the 2nd term resulting in almost full processing of the file twice

Answer (score 0):

As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) points out, [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Pattern` parameter accepts an *array* of patterns.

Such a command returns lines that match *any* of the given patterns.

If you want to determine if a given file matches *all* of the given patterns (at least once), more work is needed:

```sh
$patterns = 'Test1', 'Test2'
Get-ChildItem -File |
  Select-String -Pattern $patterns | 
    Group-Object -Property Path | 
      Where-Object { 
        ($_.Group.Pattern | Select-Object -Unique).Count -eq $patterns.Count
      } | ForEach-Object Name
```

The above outputs the full paths of those files that match *all* patterns.

- The [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs ...
- ... are grouped by their `.Path` property (the input file's full path) using the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet.
- `$_.Group.Pattern` extracts the array of patterns that triggered each match using [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), based on the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo) instances output by `Group-Object`.
- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-Unique` shrinks the array of patterns that actually matched to the *unique* (distinct) patterns it contains.
- The resulting array matching the count of input patterns (`-eq $patterns.Count`) implies that *all* input patterns were found (at least once), and using that in a script block passed to [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) means that only matching groups are output.
- Finally, `ForEach-Object Name` outputs each matching group's `.Name` property, which contains the (stringified) value of the grouping property passed to `Group-Object -Property`, i.e. the full path of each input file in the case at hand.